# Combine Two ListItemCollection objects

Tags: development, .net

I have two ListItemCollection objects created after calling SharePoint GetItems with a Caml query -

```
public Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection GetItems(Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.CamlQuery query)

ListItemCollection list1 = GetQuery(...);
ListItemCollection list2 = GetQuery(...);
```

I want to combine list1 and list2 to have a final ListItemCollection object - to iterate over as -

```
   foreach (var listItem in itemCollection)
    {
        if (listItem.FieldValues.ContainsKey("FileRef"))          
        {
            items.Add(listItem["FileRef"] as string);
        }
    }
```

so I don't have to iterate twice.
How can I combine list1 and list2 to return a ListItemCollection object?
I tried using `list1.Concat(list2)`, but it returns an IQueryable object.

Please guide.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with this? Are you only looking to display the results?

Comment: question updated to add the usage details.

Comment: Would probably be easier to use CAML and SPSiteDataQuery instead.

Comment: You can't iterate over two different list within the same collection. If it's the same list, then you just need to rewrite your CAML query to include everything needed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a alternative, you can take datatable of each listitem collection using **list1.getDataTable()** and you can merge those data table and iterate it in a single for loop.

```
                    SPListItemCollection list1Coll = list1.Items;
                    SPListItemCollection list2Coll = list2.Items;


                    DataTable dTable1 = list1Coll.GetDataTable();
                    DataTable dTable2 = list2Coll.GetDataTable();

                    dTable1.Merge(dTable2);

                    foreach (DataRow dRow in dTable1.Rows)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(dRow["Title"].ToString());
                    }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not exactly what you asked but it's the thing i usually do when faced with this kind of task: basically shove the items in a more dev friendly type to work with since the `SPListItemCollection` methods are rather scarce ...

```
var coll1 = SPList1.Items.Cast<SPListItem>();
var coll2 = SPList2.Items.Case<SPListItem>();
coll1.Concat(coll2);
```

the resulting coll1 will be not of type `SPListItemCollection` but `IEnumerable<SPListItem>` and this is actually not bad because we can perform all kinds of filtering, projection and other operations on it like for example:

```
coll1 = coll1.Where(listItem => listItem.FieldValues.ContainsKey("FileRef"));
```

which could replace: `if (listItem.FieldValues.ContainsKey("FileRef"))` because `coll1` will only contain elements where this condition is true, so that you can just use it like:

```
foreach(var x in coll1) { items.Add(x["FileRef"] as string; }
```

PS: if you'd like another type for `coll1` you could just use `ToArray()` to use square brackes for accessing the elements, or `ToList()` which is nice as well ;>

Answer (score 0):

```
  List<ListItemCollection> lst = new List<ListItemCollection>();
        ListItemCollection lst1 =GetQuery(...);
        ListItemCollection lst2 = GetQuery(...);
        ListItemCollection lst3 = new ListItemCollection();
        lst.Add(lst1);
        lst.Add(lst1);

        foreach (ListItemCollection item in lst)
        {
            foreach (ListItem newItem in item)
            {
                lst3.Add(newItem);
            }
        }
```

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried this:

```
list1.AddRange(list2);
```

This would combine two lists but does not remove any duplicates.

Comment: There is no `AddRange()` method on a `ListItemCollection` object!

Comment: Thanks Robert! Didn't notice the Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection namespace. Yes there is no AddRange() method for Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCollection object. For the above problem since we can't combine the lists, I would use the SPSiteDataQuery to join two lists in the CAML query. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.lists.aspx